# datatables and moving vertical scroll bar to left?

Tags: jquery, datatables

is it possible when using jquery datatables to move the vertical scroll bar to left of the table?

I got 'customers' that are demanding like 40 columns + and the scroll bar is on the FAR FAR right.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it'll work with jquery datatables but you could try adding `direction:rtl;` in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), a jQuery plugin that allows you to put scroll bars anywhere.